# Admin list delete and model delete() method

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have defined delete() method in my model. I use it to clear cache and delete thumbs. When I delete an element in admin, in it's details (edit mode) cache is cleared and all thumbs are deleted.
But, when i want to delete several elements at once - checking checkboxes on the elements list - elements are deleted, but cahce and thumbnails aren't deleted, so my model delete method isn't made:/

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

It's in the very first section of [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/). Django Admin calls `delete` on the queryset object for efficiency reasons. That totally bypasses each instances delete method. Read the docs.

> If you wish to override this behavior, simply write a custom action which accomplishes deletion in your preferred manner – for example, by calling Model.delete() for each of the selected items.

Comment: Read the documentation I linked to. You need to create an `action`.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the documentation, you need to override the `delete selected` action:

```
def delete_selected(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    for element in queryset:
        element.delete()
delete_selected.short_description = "Delete selected elements"

class ElementAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = [delete_selected]

admin.site.register(Element, ElementAdmin)
```